# Rubyでcase...whenを効率よく端的に書きたい

Tags: ruby

## 概要

下のコードを見てもらえるとわかるのですが、case when文の中身で全く同じ処理が行われている箇所があります。（具体的な処理内容については無視してもらって結構です。）
このままだと関数定義が長すぎて冗長だしlinterに怒られるので、短く端的に記述したいです。

## コード

```rb
def minkowski_distance(vec1, vec2, p = 1)
  raise ArgumentError "ベクトルの次数を揃えてください。" if vec1.size != vec2.size

  case p
  when Float::INFINITY
    candidate = []
    vec1.size.times { |i| candidate << (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs }
    candidate.max
  when -Float::INFINITY
    candidate = []
    vec1.size.times { |i| candidate << (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs }
    candidate.max
  else
    sigma(1, vec1.size) { |i| (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs.pow p } ** (1 / p.to_f)
  end
end
```

## 守りたいこと

速度の関係で、`candidate = []`と`vec1.size.times { |i| candidate << (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs }`は、`p`が無限大か無限小だと判明するまでやりたくありません。
つまり、一つ上のスコープにもっていくのはやりたくないです。

下みたいなコードではさすがにダメでした。

```rb
  case p
  when Float::INFINITY || -Float::INFINITY
    candidate = []
    vec1.size.times { |i| candidate << (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs }
    candidate.max if p == Float::INFINITY
    candidate.min if p == -Float::INFINITY
  else
    sigma(1, vec1.size) { |i| (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs.pow p } ** (1 / p.to_f)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

when節にはカンマ区切りで式を複数書けるので、単純に以下で良いのではないかと思いますが、何か（回答の）条件を見落としてますか？
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2fcontrol.html#case

```
case p
when Float::INFINITY, -Float::INFINITY
  candidate = []
  vec1.size.times { |i| candidate << (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs }
  candidate.max if p == Float::INFINITY
  candidate.min if p == -Float::INFINITY
else
  sigma(1, vec1.size) { |i| (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs.pow p } ** (1 / p.to_f)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`infinite?` → `-1`, `1`, or `nil` | class Numeric | Documentation for Ruby 3.2](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Numeric.html#method-i-infinite-3F) を利用する方法もあるかと思います。

```rb
if p.infinite? then
    candidate = []
    vec1.size.times { |i| candidate << (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs }
    (p.infinite? < 0) ? candidate.min : candidate.max
else
    sigma(1, vec1.size) { |i| (vec1[i] - vec2[i]).abs.pow p } ** (1 / p.to_f)
end
```